# Android NoClassDefFoundError after adding constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I've started getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:` for random class and that class changes on my every teammates machine and it's only happening for `5.x` devices, we tested on `6.0` and `7.0` but everything is working fine there.
This started happening after adding `'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`
We decide to start using constraint layout in app and since then we're getting this error

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo' }
}
def minSdk = hasProperty ('minSdk') ? minSdk : 19

//for debug builds add username to version as suffix
def username = readVersion()

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        disable 'ExtraTranslation'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxxx.xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion minSdk
        targetSdkVersion 25
        maxSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 27
        versionName "0.0.00"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86","armeabi"
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            versionNameSuffix "${username}"
        }

    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //image picker
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-appmsg:appmsg:1.2.0'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    //expandable textview
    compile 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'
    //favourite button
    compile 'com.github.ivbaranov:materialfavoritebutton:0.1.2'
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:5.5:release@aar'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.6.1'
    //    compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:0.6.1' //not in use
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub:4.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.fernandodev.easyratingdialog:easyratingdialog:+'
    compile 'com.zopim.android:sdk:1.3.2.1'
    compile 'com.zendesk:sdk:1.7.3.1'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.zopim.android:sdk:1.3.2.1'
    compile 'com.zendesk:sdk:1.7.3.1'
    // Android SDK
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    /*// Audience Network SDK. Only versions 4.6.0 and above are available
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
    // Account Kit
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'*/
    //    compile 'net.ypresto.androidtranscoder:android-transcoder:0.2.0'

    //    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'
    //Webview dependancy
    compile 'com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.7'
    //autofit textview
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    //compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
    //video compression
    compile project(':ffmpeg4android_lib')
    compile files('libs/SCTNotifier.jar')

    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.+"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
}

String readVersion() {
    def version = "whoami".execute().text.trim()
    version = version.replace("\\", ".")
    version = version.replace(" ", ".")
    return "_reboot_" + version
}
```

Update: 
I've removed constraint layout from xml's and removed this line:
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
And now app is working fine.

Comment: What is *classpath version* in your *build.gradle* file ? Post your *build.gradle* file here.

Comment: Please post the entire error message.

Comment: @jaydroider added build.gradle, and what do you mean by classpath?
Do you mean gradle at root ? 
it's classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

Answer (score 0):

Four reasons are generate NoClassDefFoundError in android:

```
1) The class is not available in Java Classpath.

2) You might be running your program using jar command and class was not defined in manifest file's ClassPath attribute.

3) Any start-up script is overriding Classpath environment variable.

4) Because NoClassDefFoundError is a subclass of java.lang.LinkageError it can also come if one of it dependency like native library may not available.
```

Before build apk clean your project.

Comment: It's happening only on 5.x devices, on 6.x and 7.x it's working fine.

Comment: in last line i said, always clean your project before build your apk. This error may be occured in case of instant run also.